# Can I assign a method to multiple Form-based Events?

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, controls

I'm constructing a Form and it has several numericUpDown controls, several checkbox controls and some text boxes etc.  Each control has a event method (CheckedChanged, ValueChanged etc) that is triggered that does something but my main quesiton is this:

What I want to do is run a single method which will update a text field on my form but currently I have it just repeated 24 times.  This works but I feel there must be a better way ... Below is an example of what I have so far.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Code Specific to the Buton3_Click
    UpdateTextLabel();
    }
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Code Specific to the checkBox1_CheckChanged
    UpdateTextLabel();
    }
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // numericUpDown1 specific code ....
    UpdateTextLabel();
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // comboBox1 specific stuff ...
    UpdateTextLabel();
    }
   // .... and so on for every method ....
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?  I want to say "if any control is clicked or changed ... DO THIS "UpdateTextLabel()" thing " but not sure how to go about it. Happy to be directed to the answer as the questions I typed into search didn't seem to be the "right questions" ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you don't want to write code like this.  You don't have to, the Application.Idle event is ideal to update UI state.  It runs every time after Winforms retrieved all pending messages from the message queue.  So is guaranteed to run after any of the events you currently subscribe.  Make it look like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Idle += UpdateTextLabel;
        this.FormClosed += delegate { Application.Idle -= UpdateTextLabel; };
    }

    void UpdateTextLabel(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // etc..
    }
```

Comment: but it would run after EVERY action returned to idle?  This sounds very close to what I was thinking ... will have to test it!

Comment: okay, this seems to run almost constantly - cool, but might be a bit of overkill ... I added a small random number to the update label and it just goes nuts until I stop the mouse.  Can I slow that down a bit?

Comment: Why do you worry about code that runs when nothing is going on?  You could restart a timer in the Idle event handler, but there's little point to it.  Use taskmgr.exe, Processes tab and check the cpu load on your process when you move the mouse around.  Getting it above 1% would be unusual.

Comment: Being quite new to this it seems strange to have the form "working" and recalculating almost constantly.  I guess I could set a form variable to reCalculationNeeded = false; and simply set it to true for all events that I need to do the recalc ... but then I guess that's no better than just typing the Update method 24 times ... I have a lot to learn .)

Comment: Testing and setting a property value only takes a couple of nanoseconds.  The mouse is pushed around by a human, it reports position changes in a couple of milliseconds.  A million times slower.  The only real cost is repaint controls.  But that only happens when the property actually changes and isn't done by the Idle event.  *Never* optimize code that doesn't require optimizing.

Answer (score 2):

For sure!  You can use lambdas to easily deal with the unused arguments:

```
button3.Click += (sender, args) => UpdateTextLabel();
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += (sender, args) => UpdateTextLabel();
numericUpDown1.ValueChanged += (sender, args) => UpdateTextLabel();
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) => UpdateTextLabel();
```

Or as some developers are trending, if you don't care about the args, you can use underscores to "ignore" them for readability:

```
button3.Click += (_, __) => UpdateTextLabel();
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += (_, __) => UpdateTextLabel();
numericUpDown1.ValueChanged += (_, __) => UpdateTextLabel();
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (_, __) => UpdateTextLabel();
```

As the mighty Jon Skeet once schooled me, this is far superior to the default Visual Studio naming scheme of CONTROLNAME_EVENTNAME as you can easily read "when button 3 is clicked, update the text label", or "when the combobox is changed, update the text label".  It also frees up your code file to eliminate a bunch of useless method wrappers. :)

EDIT: If you have it repeated 24 times, that seems a bit odd from a design standpoint.  ... *reads again* Oh darn.  I missed the comments, you want to run specific code *as well as* update the text box.  Well, you *could* register more than one event:

```
button3.Click += (_, __) => SubmitForm();
button3.Click += (_, __) => UpdateTextLabel();
```

The problem with this, is *technically*, event listeners are not guaranteed to fire in-order.  However, with this simple case (especially if you don't use `-=` and combine event handlers) you should be fine to maintain the order of execution. (I'm assuming you require `UpdateTextLabel` to fire *after* `SubmitForm`)

Or you can move the `UpdateTextLabel` call into your button handler:

```
button3.Click += (_, __) => SubmitForm();

private void SubmitForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do submission stuff
    UpdateTextLabel();
}
```

Which kinda puts you into the same boat (albeit with better method naming).  Perhaps instead you should move the `UpdateTextLabel` into a general "rebind" for your form:

```
button3.Click += (_, __) => SubmitForm();

private void SubmitForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do submission stuff
    Rebind();
}

private void Rebind()
{
    GatherInfo();
    UpdateTextLabel();
    UpdateTitles();
}
```

This way if you have to do additional work besides just updating a text label, all your code is calling a general `Rebind` (or whatever you want to call it) and it's easier to update.

EDITx2:  I realized, another option is to use Aspect Oriented Programming.  With something like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) you can adorn methods to execute special code which gets compiled in.  I'm 99% sure PostSharp allows you to attach to events (though I've never done that specifically):

```
button3.Click += (_, __) => SubmitForm();

[RebindForm]
private void SubmitForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do submission stuff
}

[Serializable]
public class RebindFormAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnSuccess( MethodExecutionArgs args )
    {
        MyForm form = args.InstanceTarget as MyForm; //I actually forgot the "InstanceTarget" syntax off the top of my head, but something like that is there
        if (form != null)
        {
            form.Rebind();
        }
    }
}
```

So even though we do not explicitly make a call anywhere to `Rebind()`, the attribute and Aspect Oriented Programming ends up running that extra code `OnSuccess` there whenever the method is invoked successfully.

Comment: Another way of showing you don't care about parameters is to use anonymous methods: `button3.Click += delegate { UpdateTextLabel(); };`

Comment: Aren't I essentially just repeating my method the same number of times by doing it this way?

Comment: @JonSkeet I could... That's not entirely a bad way of doing it, especially if you have plenty of parameters.  I'll have to remember that.  I think though I'll stick with lambda syntax when there are few parameters.  Thanks. :)

Comment: @Sisyphus Yeah, I just realized that.  Check my edit and see if that helps, sorry.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, I would still need to do this for every control on my Form that I want to trigger an update event with. Yes?

Comment: Thank you for an unplanned intro into Lambdas (my coding hasn't taken me very far yet as you can tell) - the answer from @HansPassant seems like it could be what I was thinking of!

Answer (score 2):

yes, any events of any controls can share the same event handler method as long as their event handler delegates are the same, in this case, the event handler delegates of those controls are all of type "EventHandler" (no return value and 2 arguments: object sender and EventArgs e).

```
private void UpdateTextLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your original UpdateTextLabel code here
}

button3.Click += UpdateTextLabel;
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += UpdateTextLabel;
numericUpDown1.ValueChanged += UpdateTextLabel;
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += UpdateTextLabel;
```

Comment: If the logic within the event handlers is usually the same, I'd prefer this approach.